# QTcpSocket in QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I have simple server connection thread. When you call function receiveString, it fails. However when you execute same code in run(), it succeeds. What is needed for function receiveString to work?

I've tried both

```
bool TestServerThread::receiveString(QTcpSocket& sock, QString& str)
bool TestServerThread::receiveString(QTcpSocket* sock, QString& str)
```

Actual code:

```
TestServerThread::TestServerThread(int socketDescriptor, QObject *parent) : QThread(parent), socketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)
{
}


bool TestServerThread::receiveString(QTcpSocket& sock, QString& str)
{
    if(sock.isValid())
    {
        if(!sock.waitForReadyRead(30))
        {
            qWarning() << "fail"; // fails here
            return false;
        }
        QByteArray buf = sock.readAll();
        str = buf;
    }
}

void TestServerThread::run()
{
    QTcpSocket sock;
    if (!sock.setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        emit error(sock.error());
        return;
    }

    bool ok = true;
    while(ok)
    {
        QString str;
        //if(ok) ok = receiveString(sock, str);

        if(!sock.waitForReadyRead(30))
        {
            qWarning() << "false";
        }
        QByteArray buf = sock.readAll(); // same routine succeeds
        str = buf;
        qWarning() << str;

        qWarning() << "Received: " << str;
        if(ok) ok = sendString(sock, "kaka");
    }
    sock.disconnectFromHost();
    sock.waitForDisconnected();
}
```

Comment: I've tried subclassing QTcpSocket, and I get same results :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your code ruined the process stack, or your timeout value is not enough.

Comment: My stupid mistake. I've assumed wait time is in seconds, but it is time in miliseconds. Thank you for your answer. Btw, how I can ruin process stack?

Comment: But your "wait time out" is the same for on `run` and `receiveString`.  So `run` should fail for the same reason!

Comment: 30 msec is really small time frame.

Comment: a better way to understand that is: deeper stack if in receiveString.

Comment: what my coworker experienced is: deeper the stack, slower process&thread context swithing on a multi-tasks OS. run() is just a QT thread, and it shares the CPU time with other threads and processes. Btw, normal RTT is 50ms.

Comment: Just the opposite!  Run is faster than receiveString, so run should fail and receiveString should succeed.

Comment: TimW, maybe my wrong comment misleaded you which i deleted already. sorry about it.

Answer (score 1):

What is the return value or `QTcpSocket::errorString()`?

```
//...
if(!sock.waitForReadyRead(30))
{
    qWarning() << "fails " << sock.errorString(); // fails here
    emit error(sock.error());
    return false;
}
//...
```

Note that in the run, you are always reading the data on the socket, even if `QTcpSocket::waitForReadyRead` returned false.
Are you sure you don't get the same error in the `run` as in `receiveString`, but the read succeeds because you ignore this error?

Is `run` still succeeding if you use this code:

```
bool ok = true;
while(ok)
{
    QString str;
    //if(ok) ok = receiveString(sock, str);

    if(sock.waitForReadyRead(30))
    {
        QByteArray buf = sock.readAll(); // same routine succeeds
        str = buf;
        qWarning() << str;
        qWarning() << "Received: " << str;
        if(ok) 
        {
            ok = sendString(sock, "kaka");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         qWarning() << "fails " << sock.errorString();
         ok = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: sock.errorString() returns "Network operation timed out"
That of course in function receiveString(). In run() it succeeds.